# Python imaplib fetching iCloud mail RFC822 not working

Tags: python, email, imap, icloud, imaplib

I'm unable to fetch email from iCloud Mail using imaplib.

Below is the code I am trying to run:

```
import imaplib

imap_host = 'imap.mail.me.com'
imap_user = 'user@icloud.com'
imap_pass = 'password'

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)
M.login(imap_user, imap_pass)

# Select folder named Google
M.select('Google')

typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')

for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = M.fetch(num, "(RFC822)")
    print('Message %s: %s' % (num, data))


M.close()
M.logout()
```

This results in the following output:

```
Message b'1': [b'1 ()']
Message b'2': [b'2 ()']
Message b'3': [b'3 ()']
Message b'4': [b'4 ()']
```

In the print line if I change `data` to `data[0][1]`, the number `32` gets printed out 4 times, whereas I should be getting the message bodies.

Interestingly, if I change `(RFC822)` to `((BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)]))`, I do get all the subjects of the messages printed out.

I've tried just about everything at this point and I have no idea what the problem is.

I'm expecting `RFC822` to give me the whole message, but it is giving me absolutely nothing.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try (BODY[]) instead (RFC822), for icloud this can help

Comment: Strange but this worked for me